# ASP.NET Core web application doesn't use static files stored in wwwroot when autostart on Raspberry

Tags: html, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, autostart

I just deployed my ASP.NET Core web application on my raspberry pi 4b which works just fine when I start it manually via the terminal. As I need it to start right after the start, I thought of Autostart -> so I found some methods to do so (I already tried lxde, crontab and rc.local), every time I start my raspberry, the application starts just fine but my images, which are stored in the `wwwroot` folder are missing and I get an error 404. I also tried adding sudo.

When I tried to run the application via bash (so I could see the logs), I encountered following message:

> User profile is available. Using '/home/user/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.

My `Program.cs` file looks like this:

```
using GaragenSteuerung.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRelayService, RelayService>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

I tried those several autostart methods as well as different publishing methods (one file, folder), and bootstrap did also not work when I stored it locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `.service` file where ExecStart points to the dotnet command and then your .dll.

```
[Unit] 
Description=Example for .NET ConsoleApp with systemd

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/.dotnet/dotnet Simple-Dotnet-Linux-Service.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/simpleDotnetService
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Copy the `.service` file to /etc/systemd/system/ then run:

```
sudo systemctl enable <filename>.service #enables autostart
sudo systemctl start <filename>.service #runs now
sudo systemctl status <filename>.service #checks status
```

Then the `.dll will` now be run on system boot. Enjoy! Or, to see a worked through example, keep reading on.

For more details, you can check this blog： [Creating an Autostart .NET 6 Service on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/creating-an-autostart-net-6-service-on-a-raspberry-pi/)